# How to rename the original file before sending it to user

Tags: php, header

Actually I have some download link on my website something like "http://www.example.com/somesong.mp3". Now when user click on this link they get somesong.mp3 but I want to change it before they download. I found many scripts that made it possible but didn't get exact right script. Because I want that when the user clicks on download link the file downloading should be started just after the click with the new file name as I want to use.

But in all the scripts which I downloaded, first the php processing starts for a few minute (I think it depends on the file size) and then rename it. Is there a way to direct force the file in header with new file name.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have in your code. Do you have a file read or something ?

Comment: I have readfile() function in my code.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=whatever you want");
```

Comment: I have used it and working fine but this is not the issue. The issue is that "my php script process for much time and after 4 or 5 minutes the file begins start to download" Have you any code please...

Comment: I want that when the user click on the link the file should start downloading but my new name which I will give in my php script

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. Is it the fact that it takes too long before it downloads or that the file name doesn't show up. You might be able to get the name to shop faster with flush();